# How to use ATOM FEED Data in QGIS 3.6.1?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, import

I would like to know how I can work with ATOM FEED Data in QGIS. In ealier QGIS versions this  worked with the Plugin "INSPIRE ATOM Client", but this Plugin doesn't work in the current version.

> An Atom feed is a web feed that uses the Atom Syndication Format and the Atom Publishing Protocol. Atom comprises an XML-based format that describes an Atom feed and the items of information in it, and a protocol for publishing and editing Atom feeds. -https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.5.0/fundamentals/web/dfhtl_atom_whatis.html

Comment: Thank you for the information csk! But how can i import this data to Qgis?  Im sorry but i have no idea.

Comment: For Example this one: https://geoportal.brandenburg.de/gs-json/xml?fileid=A2A5BE76-03D0-4B00-94C8-B0FB2FB155F3

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I would be looking at writing a small python script that you can run within QGIS to read the ATOM file and convert it into a format that you can import directly. If the data you need is pretty siple then you could insert it into a geojson file pretty easily.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is still struggling with this: You can still use the INSPIRE Atom Client in QGIS 3.x by installing the plugin from a zip file.

The Geoportal of Mecklenburg-Vorpommern (German State) for example offers the plugin on its website:

https://www.geoportal-mv.de/portal/downloads/plugins/qgis_plugins.zip

Simply unzip the file, open your QGIS and go to Plugins -> Manage and install Plugins -> Install from ZIP File. Be careful to choose the right folder (atom_feed_client.zip).

Once the installation is finished you can use the plugin to get the Spatial Dataset from your Atom Feed Service. The data will be downloaded into your QGIS temporary folder.