# Accessing OpenStreetMap's Spanish cadastral data

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, parcel, spain

I asked a similar question: [Accessing Spanish cadastral data via QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437078/accessing-spanish-cadastral-data-via-qgis), asking about accessing Spain's cadastral data. There, I list attempts to get the data via the official government website through QGIS. This question has similar goal: Spanish parcel data. Diference: now I attempt to use OpenStreetMap instead, and the focus is now on `ogr2ogr`, not QGIS.

(To keep questions focused, I decided to ask a new one instead of editing into the old one.)

---

I download `spain-latest.osm.bz2` from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html. ([Download link](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/spain-latest.osm.bz2).) Uncompress it via:

```
bzip2 -dk spain-latest.osm.bz2
```

leading to `spain-latest.osm`. From https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features, I deduce that I should look for the key-value pair `place:plot`:

[image]

I attempted do this with [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON spain-parcels.geojson spain-latest.osm -where "place = 'plot'"
```

I hoped to produce a GeoJSON file containing a list of Spain's plots. I get an error however:

> Warning 1: Input datasource uses random layer reading, but output
> datasource does not support random layer writing ERROR 1: "place" not
> recognised as an available field. ERROR 1: SetAttributeFilter(place =
> 'plot') on layer 'lines' failed.

Another attempt:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON spain-parcels.geojson spain-latest.osm lines -where "other_tags LIKE '%plot%'"
```

this runs, but produces a GeoJSON with lots of `"\"allotments\"=>\"plot\""`s for example, but still no `place:plot` pairs.

If I do:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON spain-parcels.geojson spain-latest.osm lines
```

and then

```
grep -irn '"place\\"=>' spain-parcels.geojson
```

I find multiple `place` keys appearing in the file, but no `place:plot` key-value pair. There is `\"place\"=>\"town\"`, `\"place\"=>\"square\"`, `\"place\"=>\"neighbourhood\"`, etc, but no signs of `plot`s. This makes me unsure if the data is even there at all.

Despite this, multiple sources seem to suggest that parcel data is part of OSM's Spain data, ie [this](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Spanish_Cadastre), [this](https://github.com/OSM-es/CatAtom2Osm) and even [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF9Bsz13q9o).

**How could I extract the polygons with key-value pair `place:plot` from `spain-latest.osm`?**

Comment: Did you mean `%plot%` not `%plots%`?

Comment: Good catch, yes.

Comment: Problem in the first trial is that you do not define the input layer and GeoJSON as output supports only one layer. Problem in the first trial is that you read the lines layer but `place=plot` is not used for lines by the OSM tagging rules. Most plots are on the multipolygons layer, and a few more on both the points layer and on the other_relations layer

Answer (score 1):

First you can use taginfo and check if place=plot tags are used in Spain
https://taginfo.geofabrik.de/europe/spain/tags

It seems that this key/value combination is used 18 times for nodes, 10567 times for ways, and 15 times for relations.

Then you can follow the link from taginfo into wiki page https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ES%3ATag%3Aplace%3Dplot and check how the tag is supposed to be used. It should be used for points, areas, and relations, but not for lines.

Next have a look at the osmconf.ini file in the GDAL directory on your computer. In the default file

- closed_ways_are_polygons includes "place"
- keys to report as OGR fields include "place" for points and multipolygons

Configuration looks rather good so far. If the 15 plots in other relations are important then "place" must be added into that section of osmconf.ini.

I made this test:

- Downloaded spain-latest.osm.pbf from geofabrik (pbf is smaller and faster format that .osm)
- Converted all the data into GeoPackage by using the default osmconf.ini file because the next steps are faster from GeoPackage. Command:

  `ogr2ogr -f gpkg spain.gpkg spain-latest.osm.pbf`
- Checked with ogrinfo how many `place=plot` there are in the multipolygons layer

`ogrinfo spain.gpkg multipolygons -where place='plot' -so`

`Layer name: multipolygons`

`Geometry: Multi Polygon`

`Feature Count: 10585`

The layer contains about the same number of features than what taginfo reported. I suppose that is because the data are not from the same date.